# MSAL generated token returns 401 when used

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-secure-api-access to create an authentication API, using dotnet core 6, we want to use to generate tokens for use in calls to one of our internal APIs.

Everything is good during the token generation.  I get a valid token (as confirmed at JWT.io), but when I try to use this token to access our internal API, I get a 401.

Here is some code:

- The setup:

```
"AppOptions": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "<guid>", 
    "ResourceId": "https://<url>.msappproxy.net/",
    "RedirectURL": "http://localhost:<port>",
    "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
    "TenantId": "<tenant id guid>",
    "ClientSecret": "<client secret>"
  }
```

- token generation:

```
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, options.AADInstance, options.TenantId);
var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(this.options.ClientId) // The client id of the target api, not the api.auth
            .WithRedirectUri(this.options.RedirectURL)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();
        var accounts = await clientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

        var scopes = new string[] { this.options.ResourceId + "/user_impersonation" };

        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        try
        {
            authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
```

Once I get the token, I use it in the Authorization header as "Bearer <access_token>" as usual, but I get 401.

I am kind of new to MSAL, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Prokurors, I switched gears on this project by moving all the MSAL code to the front end solution.  I did not pursue this issue any longer, sorry could not be more helpful.